# Overwatch Open Beta wont install?

Tags: overwatch

I have recently downloaded the Overwatch open beta on Xbox 1 and outside the game it says its ready to play and the download is fully completed with no download bar, but when I go inside the game its saying its still downloading. I waited about 6-8 hours and its still on this problem. Overwatch is a game im really hyped for and I dont want to be blocked last second from it. I havent really tried anything but backing out of the game then getting back on it. Im going to restart my xbox and maybe that will work. But if any of you have any ideas im listening.

EDIT : I have restarted my xbox and its still not working.

Comment: Your Xbox tells you it is still downloading. Do you have any reason to doubt it? 3 - 5 hours doesn't sound like much, actually.

Comment: No, I said xbox says its DONE downloading but when I go inside the game it says its still downloading

Comment: It's a feature where the Xbox lets you play the game while it keeps downloading stuff. It works well in games that have multiple levels, but it doesn't work for games like Overwatch, where any level may be loaded at any time and all heroes must be available from the start.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of OverWatch, as an icon, in your game display? Your exact wording is "**outside the game it says its ready to play**", which is the exact wording Xbox uses to tell you 'its not ready, but you can play a little bit of it'. In this case, you can play the basic tutorial, and test mode, but can not play online.

Comment: In the xbox home screen its done downloading with it and doesent have a download bar so I can play the game online. But when I go inside the game it says its still installing

Comment: You have already stated that, as a comment. I am asking for a screenshot to back up what you are saying, so we can see if there is anything else out of the odinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Said it was fully downloaded but could only do training. So I went into my games and apps and then pressed the menu button and went to manage the overwatch game and then cleared the saved data from overwatch and that worked right away! Hope that helps!!!

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart or uninstall if you do what I tried.

Comment: Sadly im already reinstalling the game. If it does it again ill see if your answer was right.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was doing the same thing. Xbox menu said it was installed then when I opened it there was an icon on the menu saying it was still installing. Clearing the saved data fixed it right away.